# Ionic error : SPAWN EACCES

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

This project was created in windows 10 OS , and i changed the OS to Ubuntu ,new projects created from Ubuntu terminal are working.

> Error: spawn EACCES
>
> ```
> at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
> at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
> at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
> at spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:17:18)
> at spawn  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:124:12)
> at ShellCommand.spawn  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:113:16)
> at Shell.spawn  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/shell.js:127:23)
> at IonicAngularServeCLI.<anonymous>  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/serve.js:392:36)
> at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
> at fulfilled  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
> ```

Comment: You need to clarify your question, and add some code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: You are sure you have all modules installed ? Also `cli-utils´?

Answer (score 1):

It's working ! I deleted node_modules folder from project folder and entered in project from terminal

`cd name`
after that

`npm install`

Thank you very much for help !